# Can't Access Button from drag n drop UI programatically

Tags: c#, visual-studio, xaml

I created a new WPF app in Visual Studio and I placed a button using the drag and drop editor but I can't access the button in my .cs file using

```
MainButton.Content = "Set output to red";
```

but I get an error

> System.NullReferenceException: 'Object reference not set to an instance of an object.'

MainButton was null while running the application.

The drag and drop editor generated this xaml file

```
<Window x:Class="WpfApp1.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
        xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
        xmlns:local="clr-namespace:WpfApp1"
        mc:Ignorable="d"
        Title="MainWindow" Height="450" Width="800">
    <Grid>
        <Border HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Center" BorderBrush="Black" BorderThickness="3">
            <TextBlock x:Name="Output" Background="Transparent" TextAlignment="Center" TextWrapping="Wrap" Text="Output" Height="88" Width="264"/>
        </Border>
        <RadioButton x:Name="Option1" Content="Red Pill" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="135,75,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Checked="RadioButton_Checked" IsChecked="True"/>
        <RadioButton x:Name="Option2" Content="Blue Pill" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="536,72,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Checked="RadioButton_Checked_1"/>
        <Button x:Name="MainButton" Content="Set output to red" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="279,100,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="213" Height="41" Click="MainButton_Click"/>
    </Grid>
</Window>
```

Here's the .cs file

```
using System.Windows;
using System.Windows.Media;

namespace WpfApp1
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Interaction logic for MainWindow.xaml
    /// </summary>
    public partial class MainWindow : Window
    { 
        public MainWindow()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }


        private void MainButton_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            if ((bool)Option1.IsChecked)
            {
                Output.Background = Brushes.Crimson;
            }
            else
            {
                Option2.IsChecked = true;
                Output.Background = Brushes.DodgerBlue;
            }
        }

        private void RadioButton_Checked(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
           MainButton.Content = "Set output to red";
        }

        private void RadioButton_Checked_1(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            MainButton.Content = "Set output to blue";
        }
    }
}
```

I can access other things in the UI just fine like radio buttons and text blocks but not the button. Why could this be happening?

Comment: Can we please see some CS? It's not quite enough to be considered [a minimal, complete, verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). I'm certain it's just an init issue or it's used in a strange place.

Comment: @JamesWhyte It's a pretty small app and I'm new to c#/.net/visual studio so I just added all the code. Hope this helps clarify.

Comment: Perhaps the variable you're looking for is `Text` and not `Content`. Try changing it in the XAML and CS.

Comment: When I edit the xaml file it says `The property 'Text' was not found in type 'Button'.` The class of the button in the c# code 
 is [System.Windows.Control.Button](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.button(v=vs.110).aspx) in the c# which doesn't have that property.

Comment: I see. I'll make a project and start tinkering. Sit tight. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

During the initialization phase, some variables are going to be null since it hasn't been reached in the call order. `RadioButton_Checked` is called through event before the button is constructed since it contains the `Checked` property.

A quick and easy fix is as follows: Check for null in your event calls.

```
private void RadioButton_Checked (object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    if(MainButton != null)
        MainButton.Content = "Set output to red";
}

private void RadioButton_Checked_1 (object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    if (MainButton != null)
        MainButton.Content = "Set output to blue";
}
```

Of course, there are better ways to handle this. You could set checked on a separate event, `Initialized`, which will handle it much cleaner.

Comment: Hah so it's like the .net version of the dom loading. Thanks. I was stuck on that for hours.

Comment: No worries, mate. It's just that the event fires before the call order is complete, so it's best to set variables like `IsChecked` and the like that *would* fire events inside events like `Initialized`. :)